# Creating combination with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I'm new around and programming.
To practice my learning I try to create some basic codes.
I know there are different ready to use solutions for my problem.
I try to create a combination program.
The program will automatically create all combinations related to a list.

My code is following;

```
MainList=[1,2,3]

CombinationList=[]

def createcombinations(List):
    CombinationList.append(List)
    for i in range(0,(len(List)-1)):
        NewCombination=[]
        TemporaryRemove=List[i]
        List.pop(i)
        NewCombination=List.copy()
        List.insert(i,TemporaryRemove)
        CombinationList.append(NewCombination)
        if len(NewCombination)>1:
            createcombinations(NewCombination)

createcombinations(MainList)
print(CombinationList)
```

I expect to reach a list like:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[2,3],[1,3],[1],[2],[3]]
```

(I'm not expecting this order for sure).

However, the output of the above code is following;

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [3]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit note: Thank you @Barmar and @laenNoCode I noticed the list problem and update it. You can see the updated version above. And made some more updates...

Also, thank you to @Corralien very fair comment. As I said I'm very new to programming (just in the first month). Last week I was only using x1,x2..etc. :) I will read style guide, thank you for the link.

Comment: `NewCombination=List` doesn't make a copy of `List`, both variables refer to the same list. Try `NewCombination=List.copy()`

Comment: `NewCombination=List` makes the two variables pointing to the same object, so you always have the same number of elements hence the infinite recursion. You should use a slice : `NewCombination=List[:]` which makes a copy.

Comment: **Off-Topic**: you should read [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). I have not bad intention, I think it just be easier to read when everyone use the same coding convention (white space, lower case variable, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thank you to all.

Latest version is following;

```
MainList=[1,2,3]
CombinationList=[]

def createcombinations(List):
    if not List in CombinationList:
        CombinationList.append(List)
    for i in range(0,len(List)):
        NewCombination=[]
        TemporaryRemove=List[i]
        List.pop(i)
        NewCombination=List.copy()
        List.insert(i,TemporaryRemove)
        if not NewCombination in CombinationList:
            CombinationList.append(NewCombination)
        if len(NewCombination)>1:
            createcombinations(NewCombination)

createcombinations(MainList)
print(CombinationList)
```

The output of this code is following;

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [3], [2], [1, 3], [1], [1, 2]]
```